# I got errors when using git remote commands

Tags: python, heroku, github

When I'm trying to use `git remote -v` command,I got

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:myproject.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:myproject.git (push)
heroku-remote   git@heroku.com:first-blog.git (fetch)
heroku-remote   git@heroku.com:first-blog.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Nishanth303/first-blog.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Nishanth303/first-blog.git (push)
```

Then I used `heroku git:remote -a first-blog` command on terminal,I
got an error something like this,

```
 ▸    You do not have access to the app first-blog.
```

Finally I wrote `heroku git:remote -a myproject`.I got the same error
as above.How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['You do not have access to the app' when trying to access heroku console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577459/you-do-not-have-access-to-the-app-when-trying-to-access-heroku-console)